# How to use watch with a function in zsh?

Tags: function, zsh, watch

I want to use a custom function inside a `watch` call. Here's a dummy example:

```
my_fun(){
    head -c2
}
echo hello | my_fun
# he
watch 'echo hello | my_fun'
# my_fun: command not found
```

How do I let `watch` know about `my_fun`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `watch` utility executes commands with `sh -c`. So, if you want to execute a zsh function, you need to execute zsh explicitly. For instance, if your functions are defined in a `/path/to/functions` file, you can do:

```
watch 'echo hello | zsh -c "source /path/to/functions; my_fun"'
```

or

```
watch 'zsh -c "source /path/to/functions; echo hello | my_fun"'
```

But it is probably better to write a script with everything in it than a zsh function.

Comment: Excellent! I went with the second option. Thanks

Comment: Another way to source the function: `zsh -c "$(functions my_fun); echo hello | my_fun"`. Not sure, how to quote it properly though

Comment: @darw `functions my_fun` will work only if `my_fun` is already defined. But if it is, you don't need that.